# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un bytearray dinámico en Java?

Tags: java, array, socket, nullpointerexception

Tengo un código que consiste en crear un fichero en el que escribir lo que recibe por sockets, separando la cabecera. El problema es que tengo una variable byte[] fileInBytes = null; y me aparece el error java.lang.NullPointerException.

Sé que el fallo está en que utilizo fileInBytes en un método que requiere que el objeto esté inicializado pero no sé como solventarlo.

Si me podéis echar una mano para conseguir que el bytearray sea 'dinámico', ya que no sabemos el tamaño final (puede ser 1 byte o 1 millón), os lo agradecería mucho.

El código en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
   try{
        //File
        byte[] fileInBytes = null;
        File outputFile = new File(output_file);

        DatagramSocket socketUDP = new DatagramSocket(Integer.parseInt(listen_port));
        DatagramPacket sourceData = new DatagramPacket(new byte[2000], 2000);

        int flagLastPacket = 0;
        int flagThisPacketIs = 0;
        while (flagLastPacket == 0){
            socketUDP.receive(sourceData); 
            byte[] sourcePacket = sourceData.getData();
            //header es mi ack
            byte[] header = Arrays.copyOfRange(sourcePacket, 0, 8);
            flagLastPacket = (int)header[6];                
            if (flagThisPacketIs == (int)header[7]){ 
                DatagramPacket ACK = new DatagramPacket(header, header.length, sourceData.getAddress(), sourceData.getPort());
                socketUDP.send(ACK);
                System.arraycopy(sourcePacket, 8, fileInBytes, 0, sourcePacket.length-8); //Aquí peta por usar un null
                if (flagThisPacketIs==0){
                    flagThisPacketIs=1;
                }
                else{
                    flagThisPacketIs=0;
                }
            }                     
        }
        socketUDP.close();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        fos.write(fileInBytes);
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar un array resizable:

```
ArrayList<Byte> fileInBytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
```

Es importante que pongas "Byte" en vez de "byte" en el tipo.

Ahora, tendrías que cambiar la línea:

```
System.arraycopy(sourcePacket, 8, fileInBytes, 0, sourcePacket.length-8);
```

por:

```
for (int i = 8 ; i < sourcePacket.length-8 ; i++)
    fileInBytes.add(sourcePacket[i]);
```

Por ultimo, cambiarias:

```
fos.write(fileInBytes);
```

por:

```
fos.write(fileInBytes.toArray());
```

Lo he escrito así en vez de todo el código para que se vea de una forma más clara.
No lo he podido comprobar, por lo que si te si te da error comentalo.

Comment: Fantástico. Me ha funcionado todo.
Muchísimas gracias.